# why there is no random.choice() command in vscode python

Tags: python

I'm trying to code a beginner password geneartor. in the video, they use the

```
passwords += random.choice(chars)
```

but when I type it in vs code there is no existing command
why is it so and., can you show me the alternatives?
thank you.

```
pwd += random.choice(chars)
```

expected there is a command for `random.choice` in vs code python but there is none and an error occurred

Comment: Please provide the error.

Comment: My magic crystal ball tells me, that you might have forgotten to import the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module. Please provide us with a running example (your code just gives `NameError: name 'passwords' is not defined`) and the full error message.

Answer (score 2):

Module is not imported, variables are not define. You can use this this

```py
import random

chars= ['A','B','C'] # define using characters 

password= ''.join([random.choice(chars) for i in range(40)]) # password's length is 40
print(password)
```